# trying to overwrite ... which is also in package

Tags: upgrade, apt

I'm trying to do `apt-get install -f -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0` (just `apt-get install -f` doesn't work currently for me...) which fails with

```
Unpacking libboost1.46-dev (from .../libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libboost1.46-dev_1.46.1-7ubuntu3_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/boost/aligned_storage.hpp', which is also in package libboost1.40-dev 1.40.0-4ubuntu4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

and many similar errors.

There are similar questions ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39846/apt-get-how-to-overwrite-existing-files-from-another-package)) already but the suggested solution is for `dpkg` and I don't know how to apply that to `apt-get`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I went with `dpkg` now but I tried to automate it a bit. My command looked like:

`for f in $(sudo apt-get install python-gnupginterface -f | egrep "^  libboost" | cut -d: -f1); do echo $f; done | xargs sudo dpkg --purge`

Then I did a `dpkg --configure -a`.

Then `apt-get install -f`.

Then `apt-get autoremove`.